# Show a number raised to the power of another number - superscript

Tags: java, android

In my application I want to show a textview of a number raised to the power of another number. For example 2^3 but with out the caret.
My actual number is in scientific form - 3.488807993e-5 and I want to show it as 3.4^e-5.
This is what I tried

```
@Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        String temp = String.format("%.2e", value);
        String base = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf('e'));
        String power = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('e'));
        return base + "<sup>" + power + "</sup>";
    }
```

However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly please keep in mind that **3.4e-5** means **3.4 * 10<sup>-5</sup>** so in your formatting it would be **3.4*10^-5**

Then your code could looks something like this (**HALF_UP** rounding and default locale):

```
String temp = "3.45678e-5";
double base = Double.parseDouble(temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf('e')));  //need double
String power = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('e') + 1);
System.out.printf("%.2f*10^%s",base, power);
```

which prints `3.46*10^-5`.

For Android formatting you could use (with variables slotted in):

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(
    Html.fromHtml("3.46*10<sup><small>-5</small></sup>")
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Do you know you know if I can actually format my number as 3.4 * 10^-5 directly without the `e`?

Comment: @Keselme I have just edited the answer with example how to display it

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can print the power as superscript, without the caret?